# What to do when your site appears with foreign content in the Google search results and rankings plumet?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

Recently, with the monitoring of how high Google indexes my site by key words, I discovered that I disappeared from the first pages, although there were 3-4 top positions. Then I found your snippet with some Japanese characters and some hidden advertising (will attach screenshot).

At the moment, all the Google searches in my website shows in this broken form, Organic traffic dropped to almost zero. However, other search engines (yahoo) give results in normal looking as they should, everything is OK.

My developer has checked all files and found 2 Trojan, cleaned them up, but it is not clear they were the problem or not.

Website: https://axemplate.com/

CMS: WordPress

To reproduce the results you can just search in Google "axemplate"
A screenshot of the issue:[image]

I will be glad any advice on how to get rid of this problem and to restore the reputation of Google. Thank you.

Comment: You have submitted sitemap with these URLs?  https://axemplate.com/sitemap.xml .  if not, its not the snippet hijacked  your site hijacked!

Comment: Thank you, I just added this plugin and ping to search robot that he can check my sitemap. Hope that this will help.

Comment: Make sure your software is p to date, CMS, plugins, templates, services such as FTP, SMTP, DNS, etc. Also, do a scan of your hard drive to ensure there is no virus. If you host more than one site, check all your sites. One hacked site can effect another. Check software versions and vulnerabilities here: https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search?execution=e2s1 Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been hacked at a server level. You will need to wipe your server clean and reinstall to be sure you've caught everything.

Currently, a normal page is served to most people - but try fetching it with Google and you'll be given a page of spam links:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=en&utm_source=wmx&utm_campaign=wmx_otherlinks&url=https%3A%2F%2Faxemplate.com%2F

These are used by hackers to rank pages in search engines. By continuing to serve a normal site to everyone else they were hoping you wouldn't notice. Sorry there's no easy answer for you!

Comment: Google has a guide what to do when your site is hacked: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/

Comment: Thank you a lot, youк comment looks like answer, I already submit a ticket to DigitalOcean, where is placed my server. But should I try to contact Google Webmaster to reindex my website after cleaning?

Comment: Don't contact them unless you've been flagged! You'll just draw attention. Deal with it and check the Manual Actions / Security sections of Search Console. If there's nothing there, just submit a new sitemap and let it reindex. It shouldn't take more than a week.